# Adding Selectable ScrollView Brakes The View

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui

I am working on a task manager app. Recently trying to edit an item inside the scroll view. While trying to do so my views just jammed and I can not see my scroll view on the view. Instead of scroll view my add NewTaskView appears.

You may see the whole project in https://github.com/m3rtkoksal/TaskManager

```
struct TaskListView: View {
@State private(set) var data = ""
@State var isSettings: Bool = false
@State var isSaved: Bool = false
@State var shown: Bool = false
@State var selectedTask = TaskElement(dateFrom: "", dateTo: "", title: "", text: "")
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.9450980392, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                TopBar()
                HStack {
                    CustomTextField(data: $data, tFtext: "Find task", tFImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isSettings.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4274509804, green: 0.2196078431, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                            Image("buttonImage")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    })
                }
                CustomSegmentedView()
                ZStack {
                    TaskFrameView()
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button( action: {
                                self.isSaved.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.7137254902, blue: 0.2196078431, alpha: 1)))
                                    Text("+")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.title)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                }
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NewTaskView(isShown: $shown, task: selectedTask),
                        isActive: $shown,
                        label: {
                            Text("")
                        })
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
}
```

The first image is my mixed-up view
Second is NewTaskView and the last one is proper TaskListView

[image]
[image]
[image]

While this code works like a charm without editable scroll view

```
struct TaskListView: View {
@State private(set) var data = ""
@State var isSettings: Bool = false
@State var isSaved: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.9450980392, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                TopBar()
                HStack {
                    CustomTextField(data: $data, tFtext: "Find task", tFImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isSettings.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4274509804, green: 0.2196078431, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                            Image("buttonImage")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    })
                }
                CustomSegmentedView()
                ZStack {
                    TaskFrameView()
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                    Button( action: {
                        self.isSaved.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.7137254902, blue: 0.2196078431, alpha: 1)))
                            Text("+")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        
                    })
                    }
                    }
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NewTaskView(),
                        isActive: $isSaved,
                        label: {
                            Text("")
                        })
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see how provided code relates to provided problem screenshots - it looks like not there.

Comment: I would be happy if you can watch my project in https://github.com/m3rtkoksal/TaskManager

Answer (score 0):

Because that is what you told it to show in your struct ScrollViewTask. You have a ZStack that contains a ScrollView that contains a VStack with a ForEach that is supposed to display your TaskElementViews(while not part of the answer, why not just use a List) as well as your NewTaskView. In essence, you would always have a NewTaskView displayed on top of any TaskElements you have. I suspect that your code is simply not actually displaying TaskElements, either due to a lack of data, or other incorrect coding. Regardless, your NewTaskView would always overlay it.

Below is a folded version of your code that makes it clear:

```
struct ScrollViewTask: View {
@ObservedObject private var obser = observer()
@State var selectedTask = TaskElement(dateFrom: "", dateTo: "", title: "", text: "")
@State var shown: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {...}
        .onAppear {...}
        
        NewTaskView(isShown: $shown, task: selectedTask)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ScrollViewTask: View {
@ObservedObject private var obser = observer()
@State var selectedTask = TaskElement(dateFrom: "", dateTo: "", title: "", text: "")
@State var shown: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.obser.tasks) { task in
                TaskElementView(task:task)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedTask = task
                        self.shown.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        self.obser.fetchData()
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $shown, content: {
        NewTaskView(isShown: $shown, task: selectedTask)
    })
}
}
```